# Verify signature in smart contract near_sdk rust

Tags: sign, verify, nearprotocol

In ethereum, we can sign a message and verify it onchain if the signer is correct. How can we do this in smart contract near_sdk_rs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the environment function `env::ecrecover(hash, signature, v, malleability_flag)`, to get the signer's public key from his signed message hash and signature.

https://docs.near.org/develop/contracts/environment/#environment-functions

Comment: How do you create recovery byte v?

Comment: I try to use env::ecrecover() but the compiler not found the function